# how to sort the data frame in the "Title "column in alphabetical order

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

and this is my code:

```
movies_taxes['Total Taxes'] = movies_taxes.apply(lambda x:(0.2)* x['US Gross'] + (0.18) * x['Worldwide Gross'], axis=1)
movies_taxes
```

Comment: the python tag is insufficient.  tag with numpy or jupyter notebook if you are using that.  But I believe you are looking for: `movies_taxes.sort_values("Title")`.  find documenation with google: dataframe sort column value

Comment: thank you for your answer.But some names have numbers in front of them,such as(3 dog and cat, 10 old man apple, bananas, friends) they will disturb the order, I just want to sort the names whose first letter is ABC ...  I want ( apple,bananas, friends,3 dog and cat, 10 old man )

Comment: @李仁航 don't see this in you data. provide proper data example and expected result

Comment: do you know how to add a picture here?

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'player': ['C','B','A'], 'data': [1,2,3]})
df = df.sort_values(by ='player')
```

Output:

From:

```
  player  data
0      C     1
1      B     2
2      A     3
```

To:

```
  player  data
2      A     3
1      B     2
0      C     1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.                                                                                            
But some names have numbers in front of them,such as(3 dog and cat, 10 old man apple, bananas, friends) they will disturb the order, I just want to sort the names whose first letter is ABC ... I want ( apple,bananas, friends,3 dog and cat, 10 old man )

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'student': [
            'monica', 'nathalia', 'anastasia', 'marina', 'ema'
        ],

    'grade' : ['excellent', 'excellent', 'good', 'very good', 'good'
    ]
    })

    print (df)

                student   grade

        0       monica    excellent        
        1       nathalia  excellent         
        2       anastasia good        
        3       marina    very good          
        4       ema       good
```

Pre pandas 0.17:

## Sort by ascending student name

```
df.sort('student')
```

## reverse ascending

```
df.sort('student', ascending=False)
```

Pandas 0.17+ (as mentioned in the other answers):

## ascending

```
df.sort_values('student')
```

## reverse ascending

```
df.sort_values('student', ascending=False)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.But some names have numbers in front of them,such as(3 dog and cat, 10 old man apple, bananas, friends) they will disturb the order, I just want to sort the names whose first letter is ABC ... I want ( apple,bananas, friends,3 dog and cat, 10 old man )

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(['banana', 'apple', 'friends', '3 dog and cat', '10 old man'])
>>> import numpy as np
# We want to know which rows start with a number as well as those that don't
>>> mask = np.array([True if not any(x.startswith(str(n)) for n in range(9)) else False for x in s])
>>> s[mask]
0     banana
1      apple
2    friends
dtype: object
# Stack the sorted, non-starting-with-a-number array and the sorted, starting-with-a-number array
>>> pd.concat((s[mask].sort_values(), s[~mask].sort_values(ascending=False)))
1            apple
0           banana
2          friends
3    3 dog and cat
4       10 old man
```

Comment: thank you, but do you know how to add a picture here. i have a problem